# Printing PHP var in PHP string var

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to print out the value of a `variable` within another string.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
$output = '<section class="cards cards--$alignment background--black">'
```

`$alignment` has the value of `left` or `right`. The above renders when inspecting:

```
<section class="cards cards--$alignment background--mint">
```

I have also tried:

```
$output = ' <section class="cards cards--'.$alignment.' background--black">'
```

But this renders:

```
<section class="cards cards-- background--black">
```

And have also tried:

```
$output = ' <section class="cards cards--{$alignment} background--black">'
```

But this renders:

```
<section class="cards cards--{$alignment} background--mint">
```

I have tried all methods I've seen on other SO questions, but can't get it printing the value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code of yours should work

```
$output = ' <section class="cards cards--'.$alignment.' background--black">'
```

If it doesn't then the $alignment variable is just empty or doesn't exist, try an "echo $alignment" before your $output line to see if you get something.

Comment: You are correct. Assigning a default value to `$alignment` solved my issue. Thanks for flagging!